# Adding more than one manager of a DL

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to add a second network user to manage a DL, but I am getting an error when trying to append a new user to the current one.

```
$Group = get-distributionGroup "DL NAME"
$List = $Group.ManagedBy
$New = get-user NAME
$List+=$New
```

At this point I just want to use `set-DistributionGroup "DL NAME" -ManagedBy $List`, but I get the following error:

```
*Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId] doesn't          contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:8
+ $list+= <<<< $new
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound*
```

I've tried setting the `$List = @()`, but that didn't help.

Thanks, 
JCGee

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this using the Add() method:

```
$Group = Get-DistributionGroup "DL NAME"
$List = $Group.ManagedBy
$New = Get-Recipient NAME
$List += $New.Identity

Set-DistributionGroup "DL NAME" -ManagedBy $List
```

If you do `$list.getType()` you find that it is of type ArrayList. If my understanding is correct, you can't use the addition operator (+) on an ArrayList because it's not a native type.

Comment: I get the following error when I try the .Add method: "Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'.

Comment: Interesting that you get a different type returned... Which version of Exchange are you running? I have updated my answer with some corrections, but it still doesn't explain why you can use `+=`

Comment: We are using Exchange 2007.